# What is the error in running npm build in react app?

Tags: reactjs

The react app is not building using the homepage tag in package.json file . `"homepage":"https://entrepreneurcell.com"` . After running npm run build , this is what I am getting in console :-

```
The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
```

Please tell me a more efficient way of deploying react app on hostinger or highlight the mistake that i am doing.

Comment: try using `"homepage": "."` as you are already serving react app from root folder of your website and you dont have any relative paths to worry about

Comment: But will that upload my code on website...I mean isn't this erroneous?

Comment: Also I tried what you said and it is showing the same message in the console

Comment: The message is for notification purpose only, its not an error. Code is only built, you need to push your files from `dist` directory. Where are you trying to push, using what service/host provider?

Comment: I am using hostinger... basically the process that I know is npm run build that make a build.zip file and then upload it to hostinger...I haven't used hostinger before ....pls tell me a proper way to host my website on hostinger coz it has become really confusing for me

Comment: See if this helps: https://medium.com/@kmchaplain/deploying-a-react-application-on-hostinger-cf2c6c43b072